Why Google android mlkit face-detection can still detect mouth landmark when I wear a mask
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition:16.0.0'

FaceLandmark mouth = face.getLandmark(FaceLandmark.MOUTH_BOTTOM);

if (mouth == null) { //*never reach here *! }

Why Google android mlkit face-detection can still detect mouth landmark when  I wear a mask?
how can i know there are no mouth landmark when  I wear a mask and
there are no eye landmark when  I wear a Dark glasses？
below is image about the problem
wear a Dark glasses
wear mask 

What you see as a face confidence is a weighted combination of all confidences related to all landmarks. Hence, if threshold confidence is passed overall face models assume that they have found a face with all the necessary landmarks. There are certain regions where landmarks are supposed to be, and among those, landmark with the highest confidence (and of course NMS and other techniques are involved) is shown as a part of the face.
